# If $f$ be injective and $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be such that $f(0)+f^{-1}(0)=0$. Is it imply $f(0)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic

If $f$ be injective and $$f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$$ be such that $$f(0)+f^{-1}(0)=0.$$
Is it imply $f(0)=0$?

Comment: yes, as both summands are non-negative, and add up to $0$, so both must equal $0$. It doesn't matter if $f$ is injective, as long as the domain and the range consist of non-negative numbers, namely each is $[0,1]$. An arithmetic tag would be more appropriate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(0)\geq0$ and $f^{-1}(0)\geq0$, we obtain:
$$0=f(0)+f^{-1}(0)\geq0,$$
which gives $f(0)=f^{-1}(0)=0$.